# If someone is blocked on my personal account, are they automatically blocked from the Pages I managed/own?

Tags: facebook

I have several people blocked on my personal Facebook account. I recently made a business page, and I know how to ban people there, but I cannot select to ban them since they are already blocked.

Are they automatically blocked from viewing my business page since they are blocked from my personal account and I am the owner? Or can they see my business page still?
Is there a way for me to ban them without unblocking them? I do not wish to unblock because then my profile is visible for 2 days and I have to wait to block them again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no specific way to prevent a person from viewing a public page. You can remove their "like", but if they visit again they are able to like it again, and continue seeing updates.

From [Facebook's help page on banning](https://www.facebook.com/help/185897171460026):

> You may also remove someone who likes your Page. When you remove
>   someone from your Page, they'll no longer like it. This is a good
>   option for people you don't want following your Page's posts in their
>   News Feeds or the News Feeds of their friends. However, Pages are
>   public spaces and people you've removed can choose to like your Page
>   again.